# python pandas json_normalize - How to flatten nested dict - key error in record path

Tags: python, json, pandas, flatten, json-normalize

I am working with a .json file from a public API (https://agsi.gie.eu/, for the sake of completeness) but having troubles flattening it using pandas.

The .json I am working with looks like this (excerpt):

```
json = {'Austria': [{'image': 'iVBORw0KxuOmB00wGjmw4Y3XTA=',
   'short_name': 'astora',
   'name': 'astora GmbH',
   'url': 'http://www.astora.de',
   'eic': '21X000000001160J',
   'facilities': [{'eic': '21W000000000078N',
     'name': 'UGS Haidach (astora)',
     'country': {'code': 'AT', 'name': 'Austria'},
     'type': 'Storage Facility'}],
   'data': {'type': 'SSO',
    'country': {'code': 'AT', 'name': 'Austria'},
    'code': 'EU',
    'name': 'Europe'}},
  {'image': 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIwA',
   'short_name': 'GSA',
   'name': 'GSA LLC',
   'url': 'http://www.gsa-services.ru/',
   'eic': '25X-GSALLC-----E',
   'facilities': [{'eic': '25W-SPHAID-GAZ-M',
     'name': 'UGS Haidach (GSA)',
     'country': {'code': 'AT', 'name': 'Austria'},
     'type': 'Storage Facility'}],
   'data': {'type': 'SSO',
    'country': {'code': 'AT', 'name': 'Austria'},
    'code': 'EU',
    'name': 'Europe'}},
  {'image': 'iVBO7OBOjcRx8LfUS+fgE/eevQiV+/D85wMd0sggG8GgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==',
   'short_name': 'OMV Gas Storage',
   'name': 'OMV Gas Storage GmbH',
   'url': 'http://www.omv-gas-storage.com',
   'eic': '25X-OMVGASSTORA5',
   'facilities': [{'eic': '21W000000000081Y',
     'name': 'VGS OMV Gas Storage Pool (Tallesbrunn & Schönkirchen / Reyersdorf)',
     'country': {'code': 'AT', 'name': 'Austria'},
     'type': 'Storage Group'}],
   'data': {'type': 'SSO',
    'country': {'code': 'AT', 'name': 'Austria'},
    'code': 'EU',
    'name': 'Europe'}},
  {'image': 'iVBORw0WjUMEoVDAKFYxCoYJRqGAU/y/+EWAAX72IOPqJ0L0AAAAASUVORK5CYII=',
   'short_name': 'RAG Energy Storage',
   'name': 'RAG Energy Storage',
   'url': 'http://www.rag-energy-storage.at/',
   'eic': '23X----100225-1C',
   'facilities': [{'eic': '21W000000000079L',
     'name': 'RAG Storage Pool (Puchkirchen / Haag, Aigelsbrunn, Haidach 5, 7Fields-RAG)',
     'country': {'code': 'AT', 'name': 'Austria'},
     'type': 'Storage Group'}],
   'data': {'type': 'SSO',
    'country': {'code': 'AT', 'name': 'Austria'},
    'code': 'EU',
    'name': 'Europe'}},
  {'image': 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANXqi7W2jLByR/ToOH22',
   'short_name': 'Uniper Energy Storage (AT)',
   'name': 'Uniper Energy Storage GmbH',
   'url': 'https://www.uniper-energy-storage.com',
   'eic': '21X000000001127H',
   'facilities': [{'eic': '21W000000000057V',
     'name': 'UGS 7 Fields (Uniper Energy Storage) - AT',
     'country': {'code': 'AT', 'name': 'Austria'},
     'type': 'Storage Facility'}],
   'data': {'type': 'SSO',
    'country': {'code': 'AT', 'name': 'Austria'},
    'code': 'EU',
    'name': 'Europe'}}]}
```

and I am trying to flatten it, such that it looks like this:
[This is my desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nNXl.png), flattened such that each facility is a row (other country data may have multiple facilities per company name), with the company data added as meta data.

I achieved this up to now by utilizing:

```
Austria = pd.json_normalize(json, record_path="facilities", meta=["name", "type", "eic"], meta_prefix='company_').drop(["url"], axis=1)
```

Since some days, this line returns me a `KeyError: 'facilities'`

`KeyError: "Key 'facilities' not found. If specifying a record_path, all elements of data should have the path."`

Although the key 'facilities' **is** in all elements of the data specified. What am I missing?

Any help and hints highly appreciated!

Comment: `json['facilities']` raises a KeyError, right? So the key does not exist in the sense that the function expects, just trying to explain the error you see.

Comment: yes, you are right, `json['facilities']` raises a KeyError, as `json.keys()` only returns the top-level key `'Austria'`. But from previous experience, I expected `json_normalize` can handle this with its `record_path`.
`pd.json_normalize(json['Austria'], record_path=['facilities'])` yields a workable data frame, however, there is more than one country, and a one-liner would be appreciated, as functioning up to now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code below should work for you. Notice the commented changes.

```py
Austria = pd.json_normalize(
    json['Austria'],              # <- Changed here from just `json`
    record_path="facilities",
    meta=["name", "type", "eic"],
    meta_prefix='company_',
    errors='ignore',              # <- Add this to ignore errors
).drop(
    ["url"],
    axis=1,
    errors='ignore',              # <- Add this to ignore errors
)
```

And this is the result:

|  | eic | name | type | country.code | country.name | company_name | company_type | company_eic |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 21W000000000078N | UGS Haidach (astora) | Storage Facility | AT | Austria | astora GmbH | nan | 21X000000001160J |
| 1 | 25W-SPHAID-GAZ-M | UGS Haidach (GSA) | Storage Facility | AT | Austria | GSA LLC | nan | 25X-GSALLC-----E |
| 2 | 21W000000000081Y | VGS OMV Gas Storage Pool (Tallesbrunn & Schönkirchen / Reyersdorf) | Storage Group | AT | Austria | OMV Gas Storage GmbH | nan | 25X-OMVGASSTORA5 |
| 3 | 21W000000000079L | RAG Storage Pool (Puchkirchen / Haag, Aigelsbrunn, Haidach 5, 7Fields-RAG) | Storage Group | AT | Austria | RAG Energy Storage | nan | 23X----100225-1C |
| 4 | 21W000000000057V | UGS 7 Fields (Uniper Energy Storage) - AT | Storage Facility | AT | Austria | Uniper Energy Storage GmbH | nan | 21X000000001127H |

Comment: Hi lepsch, thanks for your effort! I also came up with this solution in the meantime. The issue I faced with the complete data set originates in multiple countries, such that `json['country']` would need a little bit more work.
However, there appeared to be an issue with the API delivering the data. As of this minute, it again delivers the data in a format, where `'facilities` is a top-level key.
Since you did answer my original question, I will mark this question as solved. Thank you!